# Slicer with few TOP N options // COUNT

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having problems with implementing TOP N slicer into my dashboard. I would like to have a single select TOP 5, TOP 10, TOP 20 and TOP 30 slicer which will show items with the biggest count.

I partially managed to achieve this and it works while I have only one column added to the y-axis (I use horizontal bar chart) and my measure to the x-axis but when I add another column to legend field everything falls apart.

[image: 1]

[image]

These are my measures:

```
TopN_test = 
VAR Selected_Top = SELECTEDVALUE('Top N'[Select Top N])

RETURN

SWITCH(TRUE(),
    Selected_Top = 0,[count_all_current],
        RANKX(
            ALLSELECTED(Skills[Skill correct]),
            [count_all_current]
        )
        <= Selected_Top,
    [count_all_current]
)



count_all_current = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Skills'[Skill correct]),
    FILTER('Skills', 'Skills'[DateIndex] = 6),
    FILTER('Skills', 'Skills'[Proficiency]<>"-")
)
```

I will be grateful for any advice how to adjust it.

Comment: ALLSELECTED(Skills[Skill correct]) - this removes filters for [Skill correct] in the your graph. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Hi @Mik! To be honest I don't know. I found that solution somewhere and tried to apply it to my case. I'm not good at DAX and usually I just go with the trial and error method.

Comment: you change a context for [count_all_current] when add [Proficiency]. So you calculate top5 within [Proficiency]. What if you change ALLSELECTED() with ALLEXCEPT() ?

Comment: @Mik That doesn't seem to work. But that's fine. I used separate filter and that solution works for now. Thanks for help!

Comment: Great! Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I added a calculate and Selected_Top Variable as a filter. Can you please check if this code works for you.

```
TopN_test =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    Selected_Top = 0, [count_all_current],
    RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( Skills[Skill correct] ), [count_all_current] ) <= Selected_Top, CALCULATE ( [count_all_current], Selected_Top )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Ozan Sen. Thanks for replay. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Second argument to the CALCULATE function is invalid. I've managed to get it right but still that doesn't resolve this problem. As soon as I add new column to 'Legend' field, the chart falls apart.

Comment: @kosekk_g Hi, I understand. I think that maybe you can put your measure into visual level filters area on the filter pane, then select the TOPN filter (It is in the advanced filter section) then put in a number (5 for example, It will mean TOP5)

Comment: I don't think that would make this slicer dynamic then. But I will leave it as it is now. Business is happy with that solution :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kosekk_g You are welcome! Yes, It is not dynamic which I am not fully satisfied; however a working solution is much better than no-solution. I bookmarked your question and I will keep searching a dynamic solution to this problem. Be safe!